# Helm add secrets from another YAML file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a credential.yaml as:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
...and so on
```

how do I add these key, values in credential.yaml as secrets? I am able to add secrets defined in Values object by looping over them as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "ocp-auth.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "ocp-auth.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
type: Opaque
data:
  {{- range $key,$value :=  .Values.secrets }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

but this is not working for credential.yaml

Comment: are you trying to reference key, values from `credential.yaml` into the secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1、If you use the file name as the key and the file content as the value, you can write as follows：

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "ocp-auth.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "ocp-auth.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
type: Opaque
data:
  {{ (.Files.Glob "data/credential.yaml").AsSecrets | indent 2 }}
```

Where `data/credential.yaml` is the path where the yaml file is located.

Result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  credential.yaml: a2V5MTogdmFsdWUxCmtleTI6IHZhbHVlMg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ocp-auth
type: Opaque
```

Decode:

```bash
# echo "a2V5MTogdmFsdWUxCmtleTI6IHZhbHVlMg==" | base64 -D
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

2、If you need to use each key in the file as an item in data, you can write as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "ocp-auth.fullname" . }}
type: Opaque
data:
  {{- range .Files.Lines "data/credential.yaml" }}
  {{- range $i, $v := . | split ":" }}
  {{- if eq $i "_0" }}
  {{ $v }}:
  {{- else }}
    {{ $v | trim | b64enc }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  key1: dmFsdWUx
  key2: dmFsdWUy
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ops-auth
type: Opaque
```

Decode:

```bash
# echo "dmFsdWUx" | base64 -D
value1   
# echo "dmFsdWUy" | base64 -D
value2
```

This way of writing has more restrictions and is not recommended.
First, it can only process a single row of data. And second, it assumes that there is only one ':' in this row.

> [helm doc](https://helm.sh/zh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)